# Why is God represented as male or female deities in Hinduism?

Tags: gods, goddess

Why is God represented as male or female deities in Hinduism when the impersonal Brahman of the Upanishads is neither male nor female

Comment: The Brahman has neither gender nor is it without gender...it has neither name nor is it without name...it has neither size nor is it without size...that means the Brahman is everything!!! ... it's like the ultimate parent class 'Object' in C#/Java from which anything can be derived..

Comment: Brahman is the base class from which everything has been derived. Male-Female are beautiful graspable representations of Formless Consciousness-Form Matter i.e. Purusha-Prakriti or Intellect-Love or Gyana-Bhakti. Humans are made in the image of Brahman.

Answer (score 1):

We represent God with male and female deities although brahman has no gender or form because human can express love and emotions to some form of body or is represented as a body. Our mind does not work in a way that we can love something we cannot see or perceive (its possible but not easy for our mind) . Although after reaching a certain spiritual level we don't need that.

Comment: Exactly.... God takes many different forms to get close to his devotees, just like Vishnu who takes many forms or incarnations.

Comment: Good post but we need some references. I want to add that Shiva has a form that is both male and female.